# Highlight elements on heatmap using Python

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to label the elements. Here is the code. I want to directly add patch using the matrix 'b' instead of adding it manually.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

b = np.array([[1, 2],
 [4, 1],
 [7, 4]])

annot=True
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)  
ax1 = sns.heatmap(a, linewidth=0.5,ax=ax1,annot=annot)
for bb in b.flatten():
    ax2.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((np.where(a == bb)[1][0], 
    np.where(a == bb)[0][0]), 1, 1, fc='none', ec='green', lw=5, clip_on=False))
```

Output I got[image]

Output I am seeking[image]

Comment: What is the exact meaning of the values in `b`? How do they correspond to the rectangles?  What code did you try to automatically add the rectangles?

Comment: I want to use the rectangles to highlight the values in b. For example, the first rectangle should highlight values 1,2 in the first row. I don't really know how to do it automatically. It's like highlighting certain elements of an array onto the base array.

Comment: If you understand that the array of b is the number you want to emphasize, you can use the following. `for bb in b.flatten():ax2.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((np.where(a == bb)[1][0], np.where(a == bb)[0][0]), 1, 1, fc='none', ec='green', lw=5, clip_on=False))`

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't lead to the output I am seeking on the right figure as explained in the post above.

Comment: You write *"this doesn't lead to the output I am seeking"*.  That is not very helpful.  What is the difference?  Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70956590/edit) your post and add what you tried? And explain how it is different from what you're seeking?  If you just copy the code, you should get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucM4q.png).

Comment: @JohanC I have now edited the post, showing the output I got and the output I am seeking.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem of Wiz123.